# Storing CryptoKit public key in database

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server, public-key-encryption, apple-cryptokit

I am trying to store my user's CryptoKit public key on my Parse database but I get the following error.

**Error**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'PFObject values may not have class: __SwiftValue'
```

**Code**

```
let privateKey = Curve25519.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
let publicKey = privateKey.publicKey
signUp.setObject(publicKey, forKey: "publicKey")
signUp.signUpInBackground(block: {(success, error) -> Void in
if error == nil{
    // Success handling
}else{
    // Error handling
    }
})
```

I tried converting the publicKey to String via (String(publicKey) but I get the error `Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Curve25519.KeyAgreement.PublicKey' conform to 'LosslessStringConvertible'`

Comment: Did you find a way to get this to work?

Comment: @Voltron unfortunately not. I ended up using Virgil Security for encryption (https://virgilsecurity.com/) I used the E3 Kit since I needed end-to-end encryption. The great thing was that they already had a tutorial specifically for Parse!